# Creating ListView results in odd behaviour

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to create a `listView` in my app. Such that only part of the screen will be used for the `listView`, and the other part will be used as permanent information. I get strange output, the `listView` instead of showing the required string, shows the permanent information.

Here is my code:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<!-- Start of the permanent information -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.mti_student.kol_mila.MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/header_image_id"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="90dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/logo"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/search_panel_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/header_image_id"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layoutDirection="rtl">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/text_view_id"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:text="Title"
                android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>


            <SearchView
                android:id="@+id/search_view_id"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:queryHint="Search"
                android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:queryBackground="@color/colorWhite"
                android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        </LinearLayout>
        <!-- End of permanent information -->

        <!-- This where I want my list view to appear --> 
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/fragment_layout_id"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/search_panel_id"
            android:background="@color/colorBeige"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ListView android:id="@+id/list_view"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent">
            </ListView>

        </FrameLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private List<String> filePaths = new ArrayList<>();


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        copyFromAssets();//Stores the information to filePaths

        ListView lv = findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arrayList=new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i=0;i<filePaths.size() ;i++)
        {
            HashMap<String,String> hashMap=new HashMap<>();//create a hashmap to store the data in key value pair
            hashMap.put("file_name",filePaths.get(i));
            arrayList.add(hashMap);//add the hashmap into arrayList
        }

        String[] from={"name"};
        int[] to={R.id.topic_id};
        SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new SimpleAdapter(this,arrayList,R.layout.activity_main,from,to);
        lv.setAdapter(simpleAdapter);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using your main activity layout as the layout for each of the items rendered by the `SimpleAdapter` - see the third parameter of the constructor. Instead, provide the layout which contains the `TextView` with id `topic_id`, as per your setup prior to instantiating the `SimpleAdapter`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it could be  because you are using the same resource as your main activity to display the information in your list view
activity:

```
      SetContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

you should use your own view for the list view to inflate

```
      SimpleAdapter simpleAdapter=new  simpleAdapter(this,arrayList,*R.layout.row*,from,to)
```